# Loading double number in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, numbers, double

I have a problem loading a double value from a sql database. When I use jetty it works fine, but when I change to Tomcat this problem appears.

The problem is that a decimal number like 0,7 is loaded as  0.699999988079071. Or a number like 0,77 is loaded as 0.7699999809265137

I've tried loading with this sentence:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##",new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH));
Float.parseFloat(df.format(rst.getFloat("decimal_number")));
```

And still have the error.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html.

Then use Double instead of Float.

Enjoy!